# Playback has never worked for me in Audacity on Ubuntu

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, audacity

Sound playback in Audacity has never worked for me in recent memory: no sound plays, but the equalizer in the UI throbs. This has been the case for several years across a couple of Ubuntu versions and machines. This obviously basically makes the software unusable.

Audacity shows a bunch of output devices in the UI, and none of them work. There's one called `hdmi`, and then five more called `HDA Intel PCH: HDMI n (hw:0,m)` for various values of `n` and `m`. I've tried with the built-in laptop speakers, and I've tried with headphones plugged in (via a simple audio jack). Nothing works.

This is very strange to me because this is not a minor problem, and Audacity is not an obscure piece of software, but I don't see a lot of chatter about this problem on the internet. What's going on?

Ubuntu 20.04, Audacity 3.1.3.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that the snap for Audacity has been broken for at least a year. If you have the snap version installed, remove it with `snap remove audacity`. Then, install the apt version with `sudo apt install audacity`. **The audio output device you want is called "pulse"**, and it doesn't appear in the snap version (maybe a weird permission issue?). At time of writing this will bring you back to version 2.3.3, but at least it works.

Here's a [thread](https://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=119186) on the Audacity forum with some more information.